# display results from a form in theme-settings.php

Tags: media

I've been working on a way to upload a background image for months and I finally got it to work. How do I display the URL to the image on page.tpl.php? It's a form called `background_file`. Here's my code that I'm using:

```
<?php
function tsaudio_form_system_theme_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
$form['background_file'] = array(
'#type'     => 'managed_file',
'#title'    => t('Background'),
'#upload_location' => file_default_scheme() . '://theme/backgrounds/',
'#default_value' => theme_get_setting('background_file'), 
'#upload_validators' => array(
'file_validate_extensions' => array('gif png jpg jpeg'),
),);
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'system', 'system.admin');}?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upload a file it creates an file ID (fid) that we need to call back, then generate the URL and then insert it.
Place this in your template file.

```
$fid = theme_get_setting('background_file');
$image_url = file_create_url(file_load($fid)->uri);
print '<img src="' . $image_url . '">';
```

To print it out with an image style such as thumbnail:

```
$fid = theme_get_setting('background_file');
print '<img src="' . image_style_url('thumbnail', file_load($fid)->uri) . '">';
```

Not tested.

Comment: please elaborate, include what the code does, and how it addresses and solves the question

Comment: It works! The above code takes the url from the location where the background is stored and prints the image.

One more question: how do I pass that image to the image module and show the thumbnail version? $image=thumbnail?

Comment: It didn't create a thumbnail version of the upload. Am I missing something? Still works except if you use a preset from the image module.

Comment: Thanks!!!! I've been working on this for a month and thanks to you, it's finally fixed.

Comment: @GregorySchultz Great.  Glad I could help.